# Do I need a reducer if I just need to insert records into a database?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a large amount of log files on S3 that I want to process in parallel. I may discard records I don't need, but otherwise I will just insert the records in batches to a database. I don't necessarily need multiple key/value pairs, so I am mapping a single key to all the records and passing it to the reducer. The reducer will just batch the records and make the DB call. Is it feasible to just do this all in the mapper instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have described, yes you could do this in the mapper. You can collect a batch of records and determine when you have enough to do a batch insert. The `cleanup()` method can be used for the final batch, where you might not have collected a full batch and need to make sure the remaining records are inserted.

One problem doing this from a mapper, is that you have less control over how many are running concurrently, its going to be based on the number if input splits. So of you have a large number all trying to insert into a DB at the same time it might be an issue. Using a reducer you have more control over the number that will run.

You don't say what DB you're using. A case where using a reducer has helped me in the past is when using a distributed DB, in this case Accumulo, but this could apply to HBase and maybe Cassandra.

Accumulo tablet servers are distributed around an hadoop cluster. So a table will be split across these as a number of tablets. Using a BatchWriter you can insert into a table from either a mapper or reducer. However, if you do this from a mapper the insert is essentially going to randomly write across the cluster, which causes more network traffic and more compactions. Using a reducer, you can take the split points for the target table and use them to partition the data. This results in all the data for a tablet ending up in the same reducer. BatchWriting from a reducer when you have the data grouped in this way results in much faster inserts.